# What do all the dye colors look like?

Tags: diablo-iii

There's a wide variety of dye colors, but there doesn't appear to be a way to preview dye colors.

I'd love to be able to see what they all look like; Screenshots would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete list of the color dyes can be found [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Armor_Dye) and you can see what they look like (with a male barbarian as the model) over on [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX0JnktB-oI).

Comment: Another dye link: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dye/